# I can't get a null for double?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, nullable

Inside a class, I declare a property, call it A

```
public double? myDouble {get; set;}
```

Then, in my code, I deliberately leave it unassigned.

I attempt to save it to a SQL Server, where the associated column is a float (corresponding to double in C#) and is nullable.

Yet, when I query the table, it always shows 0 for myDouble.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot..

Comment: Could you show your persistence logic?

Comment: If you are using ADO.NET it has a special value `DbNull.Value` that it needs to actually store a `null` in the database. That has tripped me up before. However you do need to show more logic for anyone to help, as you aren't showing how you are mapping from C# to SQL.

Comment: So you have a problem in saving a value to your database, but you don't show the relevant code. This behavior is listed between the closing reasons for a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of two things I would imagine is happening. Either a) you've put a default constraint on that field in SQL Server (easy to check in SSMS) or b) you are assigning 0 to that double somewhere in code (which can be checked by setting a breakpoint in Visual Studio immediately before you call out to the database and working your way back).

Without even knowing how your DAL is constructed (EF, ADO.NET etc) it is difficult to give more specific advice.

Comment: Yes, there is indeed a constraint added on this column that I failed to check. Thanks, Garry..

Answer (score 0):

Try using float then if the type is float. I don't think that is what is really causing the problem.

```
public float myDouble {get; set;}
```

Comment: float in SQL translates to double in C#. I'm not sure why, but that's what I've learned. Thanks for the effort though, Chol.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the save to Sql code:

```
myDouble == null ? DBNull.Value : (double)myDouble;
```

You need to store null in the database as DBNull.Value. I hope this helps :)